# Thrown exception is always null

Tags: android, exception

I'm writing a function that must throw an exception. My problem is that when caught, the exception is always null.

Here is a simple version of my code. The `e.printStackTrace()` call will throw a `NullPointerException`

Why is my Exception always null?

```
private void fun2() throws Exception {

    throw new Exception("Test Exception..");
}

private void fun1() {

    try {

        fun2();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace(); // e is null here, but shouldn't be
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `e` is null ? Moreover put a `;` after `fun2()`. Please post the entire code with stacktrace.

Comment: I think e is null because the debugger says so, along with the fact that calling e.printStackTrace() throws a NullPointerException. As a result there is no stacktrace. The posted code demonstrates the problem.

Comment: *As a result there is no stacktrace.* Is it ? Where are you handling the exception thrown by `e.printStackTrace();` ? If it is not handled then by default JVM will print it somewhere and shutdown , may be print in IDE console . Moreover, this code in itself will not produce the behavior what you describe.

Comment: In netbeans your code works fine, try add System.out.println("E:"+e); before e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Hmm, that code would not work for me... Until I restarted Eclipse. Damn Eclipse and it's many quirks :/